# C# MVC How to change format of date in model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, date, datetime

I have a problem with date.

```
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Date_Of_Birth {get; set;}
```

I would like to change current format yyyy/MM/dd 00:00:00 to dd/MM/yyyy.

I tried solutions like:

1)

```
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", 
           ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
       public DateTime MyDateTime { get; set; }
```

// But my MVC project doesn't even see 'DisplayFormat'.

2)

In my case ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") also doesn't work.
Example: @item.Date_Of_Birth.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")

My View:

```
    @model IEnumerable<School_Project.Models.Data>

       <div id="container">
    @if (Model != null) {
    <div id="table" style="background-color: white; color:black; margin-left:5%;
        margin-top:5%; width:35%; border:solid 5px;">
    <table class="test" cellpadding="10" style="align-items:center; text-align:center; width:100%;  border-collapse: collapse; font-size:18px;">

        @foreach(var item in Model)
            {

            <tr>
                <th style="font-size:20px; text-align:left;padding:10px;">Personal Data</th>

            </tr>


            <tr >
                <td>
                    <b>Name: </b>
                </td>
                <td>@item.Name</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <b>Date of Birth: </b>
                </td>
                <td>@item.Date_Of_Birth</td>
            </tr>
```

What should I do?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What does happen when you try your different failed "solutions"?

Comment: Did you try `DataFormatString = @"{0:dd\/MM\/yyyy}"`?

Comment: You need to declare a `using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;` statement for your class to understand `DisplayFormat`.

Comment: @Tiramonium the OP has to have that namespace, or else it would cause compiling errors.

Comment: @T_Roy That was what I understood from _// But my MVC project doesn't even see 'DisplayFormat'._

Comment: Did you assign your DataAnnotation to your model class? Like `[MetadataType(typeof(DataMetadata))] public class Data{ }` ? Also, if the Date_Of_Birth property is actually a nullable DateTime, you need to explicitly cast it to regular DateTime and only then use the `DateTime.ToString();`. Otherwise it won't work as expected.

Comment: You have to use `@Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Date_Of_Birth)` to make use of the `[DisplayFormat]` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an extension method which works for both datetime and nullable type.

This might help:

```
//datetime
public static string ToShortDateString(this DateTime date){
    return date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
}
//nullable datetime
public static string ToShortDateString(this DateTime? date){
    if(date==null){
        return null;
    }
    return date.Value.ToShortDateString();
}
```

In your code, you can use it like this

```
@item.Date_Of_Birth.ToShortDateString();
```

Answer (score 1):

First, most of the time you shouldn't have to do anything to get the correct date.  Understand that that the date is always stored in the same format internally, it's only formatted when you display it.

Second, you should set your applications globalization to use the date format you want, so you don't need to format specifically.  This is a web.config setting.

Third, Display Attributes only work when you are using Editor/Display templates, so you must use `@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.MyDate)` to get the formatting that the Attribute specifies (or EditorFor if formatting for editing).

Answer (score 0):

There should not be an issue with the data annotation that you provided.  I have actually just tried on one of my own applications and it works fine.

The only thing I noticed in your question was the view that you posted shows us a property called `Date_Of_Birth`.. but your data annotation is above a property called `MyDateTime`

Was that a mistake?

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public Nullable<System.DateTime> Date_Of_Birth{ get; set; }
```

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I used these two ways (work around) to format date string in MVC.

1. Create Html helper extension method (similar to what Super User had proposed)

   ```
   public static string FormatDate(this HtmlHelper helper, Datetime? date)
   {
       //your own method to convert nullable date to short date string 

   }
   ```

and in your html page, you include the directory where the extension method is, for example:

```
    @using YourApp.HtmlHelpers
```

and to use it:

```
@Html.FormatDate(Model.Date_Of_Birth);
```

2. Create another property within the model class to return the formatted date string (probably a terrible idea). And in view page, just use this property instead of the datetime property,  for example:

   ```
   public string FormattedDate {
       get { return Date_Of_Birth.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");}
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to create special method:

```
//nullable datetime
public static string ToShortDateString(this DateTime? date){
    if(date==null){
        return null;
    }
    return date.Value.ToShortDateString();
}
```

Thanks @Super User, @Amy, and other Guys a lot for very fast answers, different ideas, and for sharing!

@Tiramonium you also had a right in declaration of

```
  using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
```

Answer (score -1):

Because you are using nullable type you can not use format string with the toString method. Need to do something like

```
(Date_Of_Birth.HasValue)?Date_Of_Birth.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"):Date_Of_Birth
```

in your view.